# struct not working in Linked List C Language

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

In the following code, one piece of code is working but if i comment that and runs the second piece it does not work, why?

```
typedef struct {

    float gravity;
    float difficulty;

}planet_t;

typedef struct list {
    struct list * next;
    planet_t planet;
}list_t;

int main()
{

    //this piece works
    list_t * planetList;
    planetList = malloc(sizeof(list_t));
    planetList->planet.gravity=9.8;
    planetList->planet.difficulty = 2;
    planetList->next = NULL;

    //this does not work

    list_t * planetList;
    list_t * temp = planetList;
    temp=malloc(sizeof(list_t));
    temp->planet.gravity=9.8;
    temp->planet.difficulty = 2;
    temp->next = NULL;

    /* let's assume here is the working code which prints all the elements in Linked List */
}
```

Can anybody tell me am I missing something here?

Comment: So which section are you commenting and which section is not working

Comment: Aside: `list_t * temp = planetList;` is *undefined behaviour* because you are referencing the *uninitialised variable* `planetList` (although you immediately overwrite the value of `temp`). Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: basically, the above section is working fine (when the second section is commented) in which i'm using planetList directly, but the second section in which i'm using temp=planetList is not working.

Comment: [Works fine here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/19d7d2dba4401360). Perhaps the failure is in code you didn't show?

Comment: @WeatherVane you are right, it helped. Thanks a lot everyone for your time. Have a good time

Comment: If you haven't already done so, please take the [tour] and read [Ask]. "It does not work" is NOT a proper problem statement. In what way does it not work? What do you expect it to do that it is not doing?

Comment: The second fragment never sets `planetList` to anything — you can't use it after that segment completes.  `temp` has been initialized; it can be used.  You could write `planetList = temp;` after the second fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointers are just numbers that point to the memory.

Consider this part of your code:

```
list_t * planetList; 
list_t * temp = planetList;
temp=malloc(sizeof(list_t));
```

Let's break down the code line by line.

```
list_t * planetList;
```

You just declared a pointer (number) and the **value** is uninitialized.

```
list_t * temp = planetList;
```

You declared another pointer (number) and the **value** is equal to the uninitialized value of `planetList`.

```
temp=malloc(sizeof(list_t));
```

You set **value** of `temp` to whatever `malloc()` returns.
The `planetList` stays uninitialized.

As @Jonathan pointed out your problem probably is that `planetList` is never set to anything and therefore you can't use it.